# Blinking icon in notification bar

Tags: notifications

I have a new annoying icon on my Razr notification bar.  It is a tiny blinking symbol that sort of looks like a tiny house with a cloud over it.  It is blinking above the network strength bars where the "x" would be if there was no service.

Anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the icon looks like this then it means you're connected to a network extender.

[image: razr network notification]

A network extender plugs into your existing internet connection to enhance indoor coverage in spotty areas, like a miniature tower in your home or office. Even if you don't have one yourself you could still be picking up one from a neighbour if it's in open mode.

Comment: If you're satisfied that this is the right answer, accept it by clicking the green check mark on the left. You get some rep for that, and other visitors can see that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

If [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/droid-razr-maxx-hd/228395-stupid-question-what-little-blue-icon-above-voice-signal-strength.html) is what you are referring to, it appears to be notifying you of a network extender that your phone could be using to get better signal wherever you are.

Even if you don't have network extender, your phone could be connecting to someone else's that is on the same network (Verizon, AT&T, etc.).